# Displaying interactive tool-tip containing data on box-plot dc.js instead of tool-tip title data

Tags: dc.js

I am trying to display an interactive tool-tip on box plot data points with dc.js. i tried different ways with d3 and mouse event to display the tool-tip. But the data which comes when mouseover on point is 0 1 2 like the indexes of dots.

[image: Interactive Tooltip required]

[image: Does it possible?]

Does it possible to achieve result like second pic with dc.js or customizing with d3 anything ?

I am using the latest version of d3.js and dc.js. Can anyone help me with the little code and suggestion etc. i am unable to resolving such issues.

Comment: If you want to display the Y values on the dots, I already discussed how to go from index to Y value in depth in [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60377456).

Comment: Thanks Gordon. But can you also suggest me something about the second scenario i.e. the pic i post the box plots are separated by line and the Piper and Hemo are also separated by 1 and 2

like the scenario 1-A 1-B.
I have achieved the 1-A and 1-B scenario. But is it possible to do the things like in pic ?

Comment: Please keep each question on one topic, so that it will be helpful to people searching the web in the future. You already asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60415797/box-plot-with-dual-dimension-and-dual-x-axis-using-dc-js) - that would be a better place to discuss adding the lines.